# Running Puppet managed redis from different user

Tags: unix, redis, puppet

Currently I am running puppet from root user. I want to manage Redis using puppet. I found redis module for puppet. I want to run redis-server using "redis" user. So is it possible in puppet to start command/process/script with different user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is to make sure your service management framework is starting the service using the correct user.

If you instead want to use Puppet to start the service directly, which is not best practice, then you can use the user parameter of the exec resource type.  The documentation for the exec resource type is located at: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec